# Can I recover my AWS deleted Service-Linked roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can I recover my AWS deleted Service-Linked roles? Is there a way to do this from the AWS console?

Comment: Most delete operations are irreversible. Just re-create the roles.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to undelete resources.

(The only exceptions I can think of are Amazon S3 when Versioning is enabled, and AWS KMS when keys have a deletion period that can be stopped.)